# Wordpress: After Changing of Domain. Getting ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, domain-name

The previous domain was 123.abc.com.  copied the files to xyc.com. Now I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED not found error.

The 2nd domain has this error. The 1st domain is still working fine and dandy. I want to abandon the 1st domain and migrate to the 2nd domain.

I wonder if it's some plugins like elementor that still have residue urls of the 1st domain stored. Which is causing this problem.

i created a file on xyc.com directory. called phpinfo.php. It can show the phpinfo.

There's a .htaccess and a htaccess.txt in the root directory.  with the following code.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten. &lt;IfModule mod_rewrite.c&gt; RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L] &lt;/IfModule&gt;
# END WordPress
# BEGIN htaccess-phpinfo
```

I dont see any error in the apache error log.

Never encounter this before. Please Help! Thank you!

Update!

It can resolved to the correct server now. But the problem it seems is the elementor themes. still stuck to the previous domain name.

I tried using Search and replace. search and replace wordpress database.
and modifying the the wp-config file with this

'''

```
define(‘RELOCATE’,true);
define( ‘WP_HOME’, ‘https://www.goatz.com&#8217; );
define( ‘WP_SITEURL’, ‘https://www.goatz.com&#8217; );
```

'''
It still doesn’t load.

Comment: This sounds like a DNS issue which you cannot solve on your own system. You need to fix the name resolution of the new domain name you want to use.

Comment: And it also looks like you commented out all rewriting rules your wordpress installation created.

Comment: "Now I get ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED not found error" - Which domain/hostname is triggering this error? Is this because you still have code that references the old domain (that may have expired) or because there are DNS issues with the new domain? www vs non-www? (Although you need both domains in order to preserve SEO - if that is a concern.)

Comment: @arkascha I comment it out or leave it as it is. It's still the same error and problem. tq

Comment: @MrWhite. The 2nd domain has this error. The 1st domain is still working fine and dandy. I want to abandon the 1st domain and migrate to the 2nd domain.

I wonder if it's some plugins like elementor that still have residue urls of the 1st domain stored. Which is causing this problem.

Comment: Did you even read the first comment I made? Realize what I say in there?

Comment: I get another error message than the one you posted: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN That one indicates that the domain name can indeed be resolved, but that the resolved ip address cannot be contacted. Are you really sure you setup the DNS records correctly?

Comment: i ping it. I get that it's resolved to the wrong and unknown ip. Yesterday it was pointed to the corrected ip. And the phpinfo script works yesterday. 

I'm contacting my host for help in the ip situation. tq

Answer (score -1):

- First, the error "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" usually arises when your computer faces a problem with resolving the DNS. This is mostly because the cache stored in your computer is still pointing to the old domain address of your website.

1. Fix 1: Clear your browser cache. ( Go to browser settings > Privacy & security > clear browsing history > advanced  > check cache as well as cookies option and hit clear)
2. Fix 2: Reset network settings. (Open your terminal/ cmd with administration rights > Then type these commands one by one

```
ipconfig /release  
ipconfig /all
ipconfig /flushdns
ipconfig /renew
netsh int ip set dns
netsh winsock reset
```

3. FIx 3: Switch To Google DNS: (Go to Network Connections settings > Right click and open properties of your router > select IPv4 and open properties > Change the selection from "Obtain DNS server address automatically" to "Use the following DNS server address" and enter the values -
   Preferred DNS server: 8.8.8.8
   Alternate DNS server: 8.8.4.4

This should fix your DNS problem.

- Secondly, Moving from one domain to another will cause other problems. If such a problem arises, as far I can recall, You would need to change the WordPress domain name settings manually by going into the phpMyAdmin and selecting the wp_options table from the schema under your database, and search for "siteurl" property and change it to your new domain name. The same needs to be done for "home" property by searching for it on the table and change it to your new domain name.
- Search online for the secondly mentioned error if you are getting into issues after fixing the "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" error. Good luck to you.

Comment: If the issue were a DNS cache on the client side of some system then one would _not_ get this error message. If an expired DNS resolution would exists the domain name would have a resolution. It would point to the old address indeed, but that is a valid resolution as the OP explained.

Comment: Also please consider that your suggestions are very specific to MS Windows. The OP did not specify what OS is used on the client side and one should assume that the OP describes a general issue.

Comment: Switching to Google DNS is _not_ a "fix" for anything. Either a DNS resolution exists or it does not exist. Either way that information is propagated through the DNS system. The OP might have very good reasons _not_ to follow this (very dangerous) habbit to rely on google DNS servers more and more, thus elevating google even further into a position of control over the internet.

Comment: @sharoqq    I see that dns server is already set to 8888 by default via the dhcp from the router.